# Google Maps won't load

Tags: javascript

I use WP Google Maps Pro plugin for Wordpress site. What I want to do is hide this map until I click on thumbnail.

So, this is my entire script for that:

```html
<div class="c-map">
  <div id="e-map" class="e-mapThumbnail">
    <div class="e-yt_video-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
      <span>click to show video</span>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function($) {
          $('.e-mapThumbnail ').click(function() {
            var map = `<div class="map"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?></div>`;
            $('#e-map').html(map);
          });
          $('.e-mapButton').click(function() {
            $('.e-mapThumbnail ').click();
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but map isn't loaded and in console I see:

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
    at Object._.re (js?v=3.exp&language=pl&key=AIzaSyBaYYvw2wvFNRg4bT_juQO-8Jil21BvxKw&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces%2Cvisualization&ver=4.9.8:95)
    at new Qg (js?v=3.exp&language=pl&key=AIzaSyBaYYvw2wvFNRg4bT_juQO-8Jil21BvxKw&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces%2Cvisualization&ver=4.9.8:134)
    at Object.MYMAP.(:8888/icare/pl/dla-firm/anonymous function).init (http://localhost:8888/icare/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-maps-pro/js/core.js?ver=6.32p:1321:20)
    at InitMap (core.js?ver=6.32p:115)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (core.js?ver=6.32p:1156)
    at j (jquery-1.11.3.min.js?ver=1.11.3:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.3.min.js?ver=1.11.3:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.3.min.js?ver=1.11.3:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.3.min.js?ver=1.11.3:2)
```

Unfortunately, it goes over my skills of JS... so anyone can give me any clue?

Comment: Brought the console errors image inline

Comment: OK, now it's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google API renders the object only if the container does really exists. 
If it is not in your html while you run it, the first time your page is ready it will give you an exception. Did it help?

Comment: Ok... I see. So maybe there is a way to render it after click on specific element?

Comment: You must be sure that the element is in your DOM (your html), and then print the map there.